# Undocumented webBrowser message WM_USER+780 (0x070C)

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, windows-messages

is there anyone who knows if and where the messages `WM_USER+780` (`0x070C`) and `WM_USER+768` (`0x0700`) are documented?

These messages are dispatched to the webBrowser (mshtml.dll): `0x070C` is sent when the *readyState* of HTML document is `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`.
The message `0x0700` seems to be sent when *readyState* is `READYSTATE_LOADING` (that's the value returned by `get_ReadyState()` at that time).

Finally, both messages don't seem to use `wParam` and `lParam` (`0`).

Comment: Best your are going to get is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931(v=vs.85).aspx  That is they are internal private messages.

Comment: It is a WM_USER message, you are not supposed to know.  What are you going to do differently if you do know?

Comment: I mean... maybe there's a header with an entry like this: #define WM_CAP_UNICODE_START WM_USER+100. In case I would use the official constant name. Handling this message is much more easier than connecting through IConnectionPoint::Advise().